# Finding all segments members of four sets intersections (ala Venn diagram)

Tags: python, algorithm

I have four sets of data:

```
A=range(10,20) 
B=range(5,17) 
C=range(15,25) 
D=range(18,30)
sets = [A, B, C, D]
```

What I want to do is to get the content of the intersection which can
be viewed as getting all the parts of Venn Diagram here (this is the complete case):

[image]

With the above example, the partitions are populated as follows:

```
()  ----> set()
('A',)  ----> set()
('B',)  ----> {8, 9, 5, 6, 7}
('C',)  ----> set()
('D',)  ----> {25, 26, 27, 28, 29}
('A', 'B')  ----> {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
('A', 'C')  ----> {17}
('A', 'D')  ----> set()
('B', 'C')  ----> set()
('B', 'D')  ----> set()
('C', 'D')  ----> {24, 20, 21, 22, 23}
('A', 'B', 'C')     ----> {16, 15}
('A', 'B', 'D')     ----> set()
('A', 'C', 'D')     ----> {18, 19}
('B', 'C', 'D')     ----> set()
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')    ----> set()
```

These are the expected answers.

I'm stuck with below code which only can find intersection that must
exist in all given sets:

```
# only gives ACD members
test = [tuple([A[0],A[-1]]), tuple([C[0],C[-1]]), tuple([D[0],D[-1]])]
starts, ends = zip(*test)
result = range(max(starts), min(ends) + 1)
# Gives 18,19
```

What's the way to do it?
Please note that I'm not interested in *plotting* the diagram. 
What concerns me is getting the member of each segment.

Comment: What output would you expect?

Comment: the intersection is nil

Comment: @Pynchia: I know that. Please read the OP carefully. Only some sections can be filled with my example.

Comment: OK, the question was read carefully already, but I still can't get it. Please answer @andi 's comment and edit your post, so that the question may be understood and used by others.

Comment: also your example code does not define `ranges`

Comment: @scytale: updated from `range` to `test`.

Comment: can you clarify what the point is here? you are trying to avoid multiple traversals of each set (as described in Paddy3118's answer)?

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about this kind of problem with a solution here: http://paddy3118.blogspot.de/2013/07/set-divisionspartitions.html

You would need to expand the x..y syntax into sets of integers but if that form of output is useful to you then you might want to interface the output with this kind of function: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Range_extraction

P.S. That's a pretty Venn Diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a sweepline algorithm that has linearithmic complexity (well, plus the length of the output), not exponential.

```
A=range(10,20) 
B=range(5,17) 
C=range(15,25) 
D=range(18,30)
sets = [A, B, C, D]
import string
events = []
for letter, set_ in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, sets):
    events.append((set_.start, True, letter))
    events.append((set_.stop, False, letter))
events.sort()
intersection = set()
intersections = []
last_t = None
for t, insert, letter in events:
    if t != last_t and intersection:
        intersections.append((''.join(sorted(intersection)), range(last_t, t))) 
    last_t = t
    if insert:
        intersection.add(letter)
    else:
        intersection.remove(letter)
print(intersections)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get this error: `'list' object has no attribute 'start'` besides, We also need the remaining of non-intersecting part. For example: `B=5,6,7,8,9`

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

A = set(range(10,20)) 
B = set(range(5,17)) 
C = set(range(15,25)) 
D = set(range(18,30))

titles = (partition for partition in powerset(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']))
source = (partition for partition in powerset([A, B, C, D]))

for elt in (zip(titles, source)):
    try:
        res = elt[1][0]
        for el in elt[1]:
            res.intersection(el)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    print(elt[0], ' = ', res)
```

**Output = the intersections between each set**

```
()  =  {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}
('A',)  =  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
('B',)  =  {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
('C',)  =  {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}
('D',)  =  {18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}
('A', 'B')  =  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
('A', 'C')  =  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
('A', 'D')  =  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
('B', 'C')  =  {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
('B', 'D')  =  {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
('C', 'D')  =  {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}
('A', 'B', 'C')  =  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
('A', 'B', 'D')  =  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
('A', 'C', 'D')  =  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
('B', 'C', 'D')  =  {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')  =  {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
```

Comment: Thanks, but we also need the remaining of non-intersecting part. For example: `B=5,6,7,8,9`

Comment: Noted, I'll try again.

Answer (score 1):

**Here it is:** The output is the set of the elements belonging exclusively to each partition. It works with an arbitrary number of sets.

```
import itertools

def intersect(d):
    """
    d is an iterable collection of sets or frozensets
    returns the intersection of the sets in d"
    """
    res = set()
    try:
        res = set(d[0])
    except IndexError:
        pass
    for elt in d:
        elt = set(elt)
        res = res.intersection(elt)
    return res

A = frozenset(range(10,20))
B = frozenset(range(5,17))
C = frozenset(range(15,25))
D = frozenset(range(18,30))

titles = ('A','B','C','D')
data = (A, B, C, D)

dataset = set(data)
titles_comb, data_comb = [], []

for n in range(len(data)+1):
    titles_comb.append(list(itertools.combinations(titles, n)))
    data_comb.append(list(itertools.combinations(data, n)))

for title, dat in zip(titles_comb, data_comb):
    for t, d in zip(title, dat):
        #intersect(d) = elements in the intersection of the sets (what we want, but has overlap)
        #complement = sets from data that were not used in intersect(d) (the overlap we want to discard)
        result = intersect(d)
        complement = dataset.difference(set(d))
        comp = set()
        for elt in complement:
            for e in elt:
                comp.add(e)

        print(t, "\t---->", result.difference(comp))
```

**Output = the content of each partition (exclusive of all others)**

```
()  ----> set()
('A',)  ----> set()
('B',)  ----> {8, 9, 5, 6, 7}
('C',)  ----> set()
('D',)  ----> {25, 26, 27, 28, 29}
('A', 'B')  ----> {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
('A', 'C')  ----> {17}
('A', 'D')  ----> set()
('B', 'C')  ----> set()
('B', 'D')  ----> set()
('C', 'D')  ----> {24, 20, 21, 22, 23}
('A', 'B', 'C')     ----> {16, 15}
('A', 'B', 'D')     ----> set()
('A', 'C', 'D')     ----> {18, 19}
('B', 'C', 'D')     ----> set()
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')    ----> set()
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think there's a bug in your code. I think `AB` is supposed to be `{10....17}`

Comment: I don't think so, I believe your hand calculation is flawed: The resulting sets must be disjoint (there cannot be any overlap) - in this case, 16 & 15 are in ABC, 17 in AC and therefore cannot appear in AB.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using python [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)?

```
A = set(range(10,20))
B = set(range(5,17))
C = set(range(15,25))
D = set(range(18,30))

A.intersection(B).intersection(C)
set([15, 16])

A.intersection(B)
set([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])

A.intersection(C).intersection(D)
set([18, 19])

A.intersection(B).intersection(C).intersection(D)
set()
```

Comment: Better use `A & B & C & D`.

Comment: It's worth noting that if all the sets involved are of the type `range(a,b)`, then finding intersections can be sped up dramatically by comparing the end points. Of course, whether it's worth doing that is dependent on the size and time constraints.